# D3.js, Need click event in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a bubble chart, in that if i click on a bubble, the title of the bubble should appear in the console. I tried some ways, but was not successful.

```
d3.json("deaths.json",
function (jsondata) {

    var deaths = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.deaths; });
var infections = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.infections; });
var country = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.country; });
var death_rate = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.death_rate; });

    console.log(deaths);
console.log(death_rate);
console.log(infections);
console.log(country);
console.log(date);

//Making chart

for (var i=0;i<11;i++)
{
var f;
var countryname=new Array();
var dot = new Array();
dot = svg.append("g").append("circle").attr("class", "dot").attr("id",i)
.style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(death_rate[i]); }).call(position);       

//adding mouse listeners....

dot.on("click", click());
function click() 
{
     /***********************/
 console.log(country); //i need the title of the circle to be printed
     /*******************/
    }

function position(dot) 
{
dot .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(deaths[i]); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(death_rate[i]); })  
    .attr("r", function(d) { return radiusScale(infections[i]); });
dot.append("title").text(country[i]);
}
}
});
```

I need the title of circle to be printed
Please help!!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You had the good idea by using the `on("click", ...)` function. However I see two things:

- The first problem is that you don't call the function on the click event but its value. So, you write `dot.on("click", click());` instead of `dot.on("click", click);`. To understand the difference, let's imagine that the function click needs one argument, which would for example represent the interesting dot, what would it be? Well, you would write the following:

  ```
  dot.on("click", function(d){click(d)})
  ```

  Which is equivalent (and less prone to errors) to writing:

  ```
  dot.on("click", click)
  ```
- Now, the second point is that, indeed you want to pass the node as an argument of the function `click`. Fortunately, with the `on` event, as I used in my example, the function click is called with the argument `d` which represents the data of `dot`. Thus you can now write:

  ```
  dot.on("click", click);
  function click(d) 
  {
      console.log(d.title); //considering dot has a title attribute
  }
  ```

  Note: you can also use another argument by writing `function click(d,i)` with `i` representing the index in the array, see the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on) for more details.

Comment: Hey, for some reasons dot.on("click", function(d){click(d)}) != dot.on("click", click). But dot.on("click", function(d){click(d).bind(this)})  is ok. Anyhint why is it so? thanks

Comment: @SERG it probably depends on the `this` context.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a title on your data,

```
    dot.on('click' , function(d){ console.log(d.title); });
```